# How to change volume of an array?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make an array of some of my sounds in my game. When a text field is clicked, the volume decreases or increases depending on the value of the number. I have tried doing this, but an error is occurring. What is wrong with my code?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
var onoff:Number;
onoff = 2
var mysoundArray:Array = new Array(tchannel,Mchannel);
var volControl:SoundTransform = mysoundArray.soundTransform;
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
options_mc.onoff_txt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tick);
function tick(event:MouseEvent)
{
if(onoff == 1)
{
onoff = 2
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
volControl.volume = .5;
mysoundArray.soundTransform = volControl;
}
else if(onoff == 2)
{
onoff = 1
options_mc.onoff_txt.text = String(onoff);
volControl.volume = 1;
mysoundArray.soundTransform = volControl;

}
}
```

Comment: what is the error then ? your codes lack indentation .

Comment: It tells me: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Insects/tick()

Comment: When I do it in debug mode, it shows me the error is where volControl.volume = 1;

Comment: `volControl` is a `SoundTransform` instance, not array. Therefore, your question is not about Array, perhaps?

Comment: I want some of my sounds to be in an array so I can adjust their volume universally. Is this the correct way I am putting my sounds in an array?

Answer (score 0):

Your codes have multiple errors.

Error 1: where does `tchannel` and `Mchannel` come from?

```
var mysoundArray:Array = new Array(tchannel,Mchannel);
```

Error 2: Array `mysoundArray` does not have child object called `soundTransform`.

```
var volControl:SoundTransform = mysoundArray.soundTransform;
```

Therefore, the object `volControl` is null. Fix the above errors and your issue will be fixed.